# Do <field: textarea> fields not get a tooltip popup by default?

Tags: spring, dojo, textarea, spring-roo

I have created a spring roo webapp. In the roo-generated update.jspx pages there are forms with different fields:

```
<form:update ..>
 <field:input ../>
 <field:textarea ../>
 ...
</form:update>
```

After some searching and trying to find out what happens in the dojo/dijit JavaScript functions, I have found my question asked here:

[do  fields not get a tooltip popup by default?](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/roo/114838-do-field-textarea-fields-not-get-a-tooltip-popup-by-default)

Unanswered:

> do  fields not get a tooltip popup by default?
>
> Mar 12th, 2012, 03:53 PM
>
> I have @Size(max=60) on some attributes on one of
>   my entities, so they get displayed as a textarea, which is great (took
>   some searching around to find out how to trigger this behavior).
>
> I've noticed though that the  fields get the popup
>   tooltip help text by default, but the  fields
>   apparently do not. Is this by design, or have I broken something that
>   stops this from working? :-)

..Could not express it better! Are there any answers to this question from 2012?